# Letter guessing game in C program, confused of errors

Tags: c

I am trying to do a letter guessing game in C language by using Visual Studio 2012, but I keep getting errors and warnings and I have no clue how to fix them. The errors that I keep receiving are:

1.)Warning  1   warning C4133: 'function' : incompatible types - from 'FILE *' to 'const char *'

2.)Warning  2   warning C4047: '=' : 'FILE *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int (__cdecl *)(FILE *)'

3.)Error    3   error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)

4.)Error    4   error C1004: unexpected end-of-file found

5.)IntelliSense: argument of type "FILE *" is incompatible with parameter

6.)IntelliSense: a value of type "int (__cdecl *)(FILE *_File)" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "FILE *"

I also see errors that say 'expected a declaration.'
Every time I try to fix things, I end up causing more issues in other areas. Could someone give me assistance with this? Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXGUESSES 5

int SingleGame(char file_letter);

int main()
{
    //declare additional variables
int PlayGames = 4,
i = 0;
FILE * infile;
char letter;
    //display instructions
    printf("Welcome to the Letter Guessing Game!\n");
    printf("You will enter the number of games that you want to play, which is 1-4 games\n");
    printf("You have 5 chances to guess each letter\n");
    printf("Let's begin!\n");

    //open file
    infile = fopen("lettersin.txt", "r");

    //get number of games to play
    printf("How many games would you like to play?(1-4)\n");
    scanf("%d", &PlayGames);

    for(i=0;i<PlayGames;i++)
    {
        //get a letter from file
        scanf(infile, " %c", &letter);

        //Play one game
        printf("Let's play a game %d\n", i);

        //check for win or lose
        SingleGame (letter);
    }

    //close file
    infile = fclose;
    return 0;
}
int SingleGame(char file_letter);
{

//Function definitions
    int numGuesses = 0;
    while(numGuesses < MAXGUESSES);
    char RetrieveGuess = 0;
    int PlayGames = 0;

    {
        printf("Enter a guess\n");
        scanf("%c" , &RetrieveGuess);
        if(file_letter == RetrieveGuess);
        {
            printf("You guessed it!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if(file_letter>RetrieveGuess)
            {
                printf("The letter you are trying to guess comes before:%d\n",RetrieveGuess)
            }
            {
            else if(file_letter<RetrieveGuess)
            {
                printf("The letter you are trying to guess comes after:%d\n", RetrieveGuess)
            }


            {
            numGuesses = numGuesses +1;
            }
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your `SingleGame` function?

Answer (score 1):

> 1.)Warning 1 warning C4133: 'function' : incompatible types - from 'FILE *' to 'const char *'

```
scanf(infile, " %c", &letter);
```

If you want to read from a specific `FILE *`, use `fscanf()`:

```
fscanf(infile, " %c", &letter);
```

> 2.)Warning 2 warning C4047: '=' : 'FILE *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int (__cdecl *)(FILE *)'

```
infile = fclose;
```

You want to call `fclose()` and not assign it to `infile` (which also doesn't have a compatible type):

```
fclose(infile);
```

> 3.)Error 3 error C2449: found '{' at file scope (missing function header?)

```
int SingleGame(char file_letter);
```

The semicolon makes that a function declaration/protoype, but you want to define one. Delete it.

The semicolon here is a so-called `null statement`). This means if both variables are equal, then nothing will be done.

```
if(file_letter == RetrieveGuess);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues with your code here. It is always difficult to work on more than one problem at a time. My advice is that you copy all this code into a different file, and rebuild this file one line at a time and only add another line after you compile the current file error and warning free.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of syntax errors were in code. I've corrected them for you. Although not sure logically the code is correct or not. You got to run and see.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXGUESSES 5

void SingleGame(char file_letter);

int main()
{
    //declare additional variables
    int PlayGames = 4,
    i = 0;
    FILE* infile;
    char letter;
    //display instructions
    printf("Welcome to the Letter Guessing Game!\n");
    printf("You will enter the number of games that you want to play, which is 1-4 games\n");
    printf("You have 5 chances to guess each letter\n");
    printf("Let's begin!\n");

    //open file
    infile = fopen("lettersin.txt", "r");

    //get number of games to play
    printf("How many games would you like to play?(1-4)\n");
    scanf("%d", &PlayGames);

    for(i=0;i<PlayGames;i++)
    {
        //get a letter from file
        fscanf(infile, " %c", &letter);

        //Play one game
        printf("Let's play a game %d\n", i);

        //check for win or lose
        SingleGame (letter);
    }

    //close file
    fclose(infile);
    return 0;
}

void SingleGame(char file_letter)
{
//Function definitions
    int numGuesses = 0;
    while(numGuesses < MAXGUESSES)
    {
        char RetrieveGuess = 0;
        int PlayGames = 0;

        printf("Enter a guess\n");
        scanf("%c" , &RetrieveGuess);
        if(file_letter == RetrieveGuess)
        {
            printf("You guessed it!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            if(file_letter>RetrieveGuess)
            {
                printf("The letter you are trying to guess comes before:%d\n",RetrieveGuess);
            }
            else if(file_letter<RetrieveGuess)
            {
                printf("The letter you are trying to guess comes after:%d\n", RetrieveGuess);
            }

            numGuesses = numGuesses +1;
        }
    }
}
```